# What is the expected number of throws of a die (with 6 faces numbered 1 through 6), until we see four ‘sixes’ turn up regardless of any order?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

We throw a die until four 'sixes' turn up regardless of any order. If 'X' represents the number of throws of the die, then what is the probability mass function for 'X'? What is the value of E(X) in this case?

Comment: sum of expectations ... $6\cdot4=24$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\ X=X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4\ $, where $\ X_1\ $ is the number of the throw on which the first six turns up, and, for $\ 2\le n\le 4\ $, and $\ \sum_\limits{i=1}^n X_i\ $ is the number of the throw on which the $\ n^\text{th}\ $ six turns up.  The random variables $\ X_i\ $ are independent with identical PMF
$$
\text{Prob}\left(X_i=t\right) = \frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{t-1}\ ,
$$
so the PMF of $\ X\ $ is the fourfold convolution of this one:
\begin{align}
\text{Prob}\left(X_1+X_2=t\,\right)&=\text{Prob}\left(X_3+X_4=t\,\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{36}\sum_{i=1}^{t-1}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{i-1}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{t-i-1}\\
&=\frac{t-1}{36}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{t-2}\ \text{for }\ t\ge 2\\
 \therefore \text{Prob}\left(X=t\,\right)&=\frac{1}{36^2}\sum_{i=2}^{t-2}(i-1)(t-i-1)\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{i-2}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{t-i-2}\\
&=\frac{t-1\choose 3}{36^2}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{t-4}\ \text{for }\ t\ge 4\ .
\end{align}
As [Don Thousand](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/572204/don-thousand) has already noted, $\ E(X)=4E\left(X_i\right)\ $, where
\begin{align}
E\left(X_i\right)&=\frac{1}{6}\sum_\limits{t=1}^\infty t\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{t-1}\\
&=6\ .
\end{align}

**Generalisation:** The form of the expressions for these PMFs suggests that if $\ T_n\ $ is the number of the throw on which the $\ n^\text{th}\ $ six turns up for any $\ n\ $, then
$$
\text{Prob}\left(T_n=t\right)=\frac{t-1\choose n-1}{6^n}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{t-n}\ .\,
$$
and, in fact, this identity isn't difficult to prove by induction.

Comment: Thanks @lonzaleggiera for the answer. Is it possible to find any joint pmf for X, that would follow the axiom for total probability $ \sum_{i=1}^∞ P(X = x_i) = 1 $ ? Because hence, we might be able to calculate probability like P(X ≤ 9).

Comment: Yes, you just need to work out the fourfold convolution of the distribution of the $\ X_i\ $.  I've now added the derivation of this.

Comment: Thanks @lonzaleggiera once again.